# Code and Terminal Screenshots

Tags: discussion

There are quite some questions and answers with screenshots of code and compiler output.

It seems to me that practice is suboptimal since it inhibits the searchability. Crawlers, presently, cannot look into the image contents. That in turn leads to some people not finding the answers and potentially for duplicates.

Should we do something about it? What can we do about it?

Comment: Related FAQ on MSO: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1478931) And a related discussion on MSE: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/335251)

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to comment on questions/answers, kindly asking the users not to post screenshots and briefly explaining why.

For power users and moderators, I strongly recommend using the browser extension [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) ([Github](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments)). You could create a custom comment for screenshots of terminals.

Answer (score 0):

We could edit the [how to ask a good question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) help article, unclear how to do that though, I don't see a way as a mod. Suggesting that screenshots of text output will not be generally accepted, and everyone will be asked to use code-block delimited logs/snippets.

Comment: Site mods can't edit most Help Center articles to customize them for their own site (because if we edit it on only one site, then changes to the network-wide version of the article won't be automatically propagated to the sites that have overridden it with their own site-specific version). The only parts of the Help Center that are mod-editable by default are the [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) page, and the introductory section at the top of the [main Help Center page](/help).

Comment: The CMs can edit Help Center articles to make changes network-wide upon request (the site mods can escalate a post on this site's Meta to the CMs by adding the [status-review] tag). You can also ask us to create a site-specific override of a page if there's a really compelling reason to do so, but this is rarely necessary.